# UWP, Sometimes AppWindow.TryCreateAsync throws a COMException "Class not registered"

Tags: c#, uwp, comexception

In my UWP app I need to open a second window, which we do by calling `AppWindow.TryCreateAsync()` API.

Sometimes, and only on some devices (e.g. on a Surface GO), this API throws a `COMException "Class not registered"`.

Even during the execution of the app, I can reproduce this behavior:

1. app in single window mode; call to `AppWindow.TryCreateAsync()` => OK,
   no problem at all
2. close the second window, and go back to single-window mode
3. open again a second window by calling `AppWindow.TryCreateAsync()` => `COMException`
4. wait some seconds
5. retry to open again a second window by calling `AppWindow.TryCreateAsync()` => OK, no problem.

How can a `"Class not registered" Exception`, which seems to be a compilation or assembly problem, to appear and to disappear on a running app?

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: So you googled the error message and you know *that* is not supposed to happen in a UWP app.  Can't post a repro either, you'll have to take this one to Microsoft Support.  They still like a minimum repro, that's not different.  Be sure to post back the resolution.

Comment: I used the `AppWindow.TryCreateAsync()` method to create a second window and followed your repro steps, but I didn't receive the exception, I just tested it on PC. What's your model of Surface Go? And if you tested it on PC, can the same error occur?

Comment: This issue happens only on some specific devices. E.g. on my PC (an HP Spectre) never occurred. On Surface GO, SOMETIMES happens.